# How to split a module into 2 or 3 modules

Tags: python, class, import

I would like to split the following (working script) into 2 or 3 separate modules

```
class Comp():
    Name = ''
    Type = ''
Var = 'Bob'
Var1 = 'Bob'
Var2 = 'Tall'

exec(Var + ' = ' + 'Comp()')
exec(Var + '.' + 'Name' + ' = ' + "'" + Var1 + "'")
exec(Var + '.' + 'Type' + ' = ' + "'" + Var2 + "'")

print(Bob.Name, Bob.Type)

>> Bob Tall
```

How to write the import statements for modules A, B and C, to achieve the above. A and B may be combined, C must be separate. I do NOT want to use Dictionaries!

```
#A.py - create a class in  module A 
class Comp
    Name  = ''
    Type  = ''

#B.py - instantiate Comp in module B
def Inst(Var1, Var2):
    Var1 = Comp
    Var1.Name = Var1
    Var1.Type = Var2
    
#C.py - supply the variables from module C    
Inst('Bob', 'Tall')
print(Bob.Name, Bob.Type)
>> Bob Tall
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else need to do this, here is the answer:

```
# A.py
class Comp:
    Name = ''
    Type = ''

#B.py
from A import*
def Inst(Var1, Var2):
    temp = Var1
    Var1 = Comp
    Var1.Name = temp
    Var1.Type = Var2
    return Var1

#C.py
from B import Inst
name = Inst('Bob', 'Tall')
print(name.Name, name.Type)
>> Bob Tall
```

P.S. This was not my work. It was done by Muhammad Moaz, a Fiverr contractor